# In C, is a global pointer initialized by malloc() in the data segment or the BSS?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, memory, malloc

From what I understand, the data segment is for the initialized global / static variables, and the BSS segment is for the uninitialized data segment. So for example:

```
int a = 10;             // data segment
int b;                  // BSS
int main(){
    int c  = 10;        // stack
    int* d = malloc()   // heap
    return 0; 
}
```

However, in a pdf I found for one of my classes, it says that a global pointer initialized to the address returned by `malloc()` is in the BSS. Shouldn't it be in the data segment since the pointer is actually initialized to something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, there's no such thing as a global pointer initialized by `malloc`, as that would mean having an executable statement outside of a function.  For example, this:

```
char *p = malloc(10);

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Will fail to compile.

You can however do this in C++.  In that case, such a variable will be located in the BSS section since it is not initialized at compile time.  The `malloc` function will instead be called by internal startup functions before the `main` function is called.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard doesn't define where data allocated by `malloc()` comes from.  It doesn't define text segments, data segments, BSS segments, or any other segments. In practice, allocated memory comes from "the heap", which is neither the data segment nor the BSS segment.  Those are for (non-dynamically allocated) variables with [static duration](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4).  The memory allocated by `malloc()` et al has "allocated duration".

In your code, `d` (the pointer) has "automatic duration", the same as `c`.  The memory it points at, though, is from "the heap".

The PDF is correct, though.  If you have a global pointer, `int *g;` (or `int *g = 0;` or `int *g = NULL;`), then the variable is probably in the BSS segment (if it isn't explicitly uninitialized, it will be in the BSS segment; with the explicit null pointer initializers, it could be in the BSS segment, but it could be in the data segment).  In C, you can't write an initializer for a global pointer that calls a function (but in C++ you can, but you shouldn't be using `malloc()` in C++ anyway).  So, the pointer `g` would be in the data segment or the BSS segment, but the data it is later made to point to by a call to `malloc()` will be in "the heap".